# Why I am getting null in POST in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api

I have a POST method in my web api and its works fine in POSTMAN.
This is my web api code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public IEnumerable<TuitionHistoryStudent> GetTuitionHistoryStudent(TuitionHistoryStudent student)
    {
        List<TuitionHistoryStudent> tuitionHistoryList = new List<TuitionHistoryStudent>();
        try
        {
            Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTuitionHistoryStudent", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID", student.StundentID);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TuitionHistoryStudent tuitionHistory = new TuitionHistoryStudent();
                tuitionHistory.StundentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["StudentID"]);
                tuitionHistory.TutionTeacherID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TutionTeacherID"]);
                tuitionHistory.Class = reader["Class"].ToString();
                tuitionHistory.Subject = reader["Subject"].ToString();
                tuitionHistory.Time = reader["Time"].ToString();
                tuitionHistory.Date = reader["Date"].ToString();
                tuitionHistory.Ratting = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Rating"]);
                tuitionHistoryList.Add(tuitionHistory);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return tuitionHistoryList;

    }
```

And this is my code where is call my url:

```
public async void ShowTuitionSistoryAsync()
    {
        int StudentID = 1017;
        string url = "my_url";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { StudentID = StudentID });
        StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(true);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if(result != null)
        {
            var ListOfHistory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TuitionHistoryStudent>>(result);
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }

    }
```

I am always getting this empty result "[]".
Can you guys tell me where is the problem?

Comment: what is the http status code that you get in response? Is it a success status code? I see you are catching any exceptions in GetTuitionHistoryStudents method. Can you debug the API and verify if the catch is not triggered?

Comment: Nah. Catch is not triggering. In web api I checked. It always go in while loop. Complete the loop and return list of object i want. I dont know if the problem occurring when I am trying to call my url.

Comment: which http status code do you get in response?

Comment: Status code is: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK

Comment: put a breakpoint inside GetTuitionHistoryStudent, and see whats arriving there

Comment: I did bro, it works fine. No error, nothing. Goes to the while loop, assign values in class and return it. Can you give me your facebook account so that I can show you!

Comment: Or is there any option that i can put some picture in comment